# How to find features and targets for subset of data?

Tags: python, pytorch

I'm trying to find the specific amount of features in a subset of a dataset. Below is an example code:

```
# import the required modules
import torch
import torchvision
from torchvision.datasets import CIFAR10
from collections import Counter

trainset = CIFAR10(root='./data', train=True, download=True, transform=torchvision.transforms.ToTensor())

indices = torch.arange(3000)
new_trainset_split = torch.utils.data.Subset(trainset, indices)
```

This outputs a 3000 datapoints, which is exactly what I want. However when I try the next line of code to see, how many types of each features there are (in this case, how many of the datapoints are 1's, 2's, 3's etc..), it gives me the error:

```
print(dict(Counter(new_trainset_split.targets)))
```

> AttributeError: 'Subset' object has no attribute 'targets'

How do I find features and targets for subset of data?

Comment: The features of CIFAR are 32x32 and there are 10 numbers, from 0 to 9. So, what exactly are you looking for?

Comment: I'm looking to get 300 of each of the numbers.

Comment: Like value_counts()

Comment: Sorry, I dont understand. Could you elaborate more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why you are not getting access to targets is because [`data.Subset`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html#torch.utils.data.Subset) simply doesn't implement the attributes as the wrapped `data.Dataset` (in your case `datasets.CIFAR10`) implements.

However, an easy workaround is to simply filter your initial dataset's targets with `indices` directly:

```
>>> Counter(trainset.targets[i] for i in indices) 
Counter({0: 299,
         1: 287,
         2: 322,
         3: 285,
         4: 311,
         5: 279,
         6: 312,
         7: 297,
         8: 308,
         9: 300})
```

Comment: Thanks Ivan, that is perfect. On the side note, how would I make it so that I get exactly 300 datapoints for each target?

Comment: You can't ensure an exact number of instances per class because the sampling is done randomly. On average you will find the same statistics in the subset as the original dataset but you will have a disparity.

Answer (score 0):

The `subset` class inherits from the `dataset` class.
Thus, you just need to call the `dataset` class in a way more simple way:

```
print(dict(Counter(new_trainset_split.dataset.targets)))
```

the output should be:

```
{6: 5000, 9: 5000, 4: 5000, 1: 5000, 2: 5000, 7: 5000, 8: 5000, 3: 5000, 5: 5000, 0: 5000}
```

Comment: This solution is not what OP asked for. This solution counts trainset's targets; however new_trainset_split's targets need to be counted.